# Azure DevOps Pull Request policy requiring one of two required reviewers

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

In my team, we have 6 developers, 2 of them are tech leads, so at least one of them needs to approve the PR. The other 4 developers are optional.

Is there a way to allow to complete the PR if any one of the required reviewers/approvers approves the PR?

I managed to add the two tech leads as required reviewers, but the issue is that both of them need to approve the PR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can setup a minimum of reviewers as a branch policy:

[image: branch policy]

Then only use optional reviewers in the PR, as the policy already enforces one to be mandatory.
[image]

To achieve that one of those reviewers is a tech lead, create a [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-remove-manage-user-group-security-group?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) for the tech leads and make this group mandatory.

As soon as one of the members approves the PR it counts for the mandatory reviewer, and adds the user who approved it automatically as optional reviewer.

[image: example of group reviewer]

This group, tech leads in your use case, can then be configured as a branch policy, in Settings > Repositories > Build policy: :
[image: tech lead group]

Since this is a branch policy, the look and feel is slightly different in the PR, but never the less your goals is achieved:

[image: tech lead pr accept = tonie]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding both developers themselves as required reviewers, [create a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-remove-manage-user-group-security-group?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#create-a-custom-security-group) called e.g. Tech Leads, add both the tech leads there and add the group as a required reviewer. Approval from any member of the group counts as approval from the group.

It is documented in the [branch policies docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#automatically-include-code-reviewers):

> Or, select **Required** if pull requests can't be completed until:
>
> - Every individual added as a reviewer approves the changes.
> - At least one person in every group added as a reviewer approves the changes.
> - If only one group is required, the minimum number of members you specify approve the changes.